# How to set HTML table cell to inherit its size?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with height/width 100% inside a table.
I define the table size, but it doesn't work until I define the TD size as well.
How can I make the TD to inherit the table size so that I don't have to duplicate the size in CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.g {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}

img {
  height:inherit;
  width:inherit;
}

td, tr, tbody {
  height:inherit;
  width:inherit;
}
```

```html
<table class="g" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/stgeorge12-hp.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="g"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/stgeorge12-hp.png"></div>
```

Comment: can I ask why you need it to inherit?

Comment: not really possible.. you can set the width of the `<td>` to make it really inherit the `<table>` width - http://jsfiddle.net/CgEhg/2/  but as you can see the image is being shrunk proportionally and it's not square

Comment: neat! doesn't work in IE7 though.. however if you don't care about "ancient" browsers - it's a nice solution

Comment: Thanks, your help was crucial.

Comment: I have edited your post but it says "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." any idea?

Comment: Yep, I approved it (as the owner)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above example, set 100% so that the table stretches automatically according to its content.

```
   table
    {
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
    }


    td,tr,tbody
    {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
```